# IIS 7 Basic Site Setup

Tags: iis-7

Getting the following error on IIS 7 when attempting to access the default.htm during the setup of a basic test site.

403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.

Added read and list permissions for IUSR and IIS_IUSRS. Running under the default application pool. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your Default Documents are in order. You can check them from either the Home Folder tab of the Web Site Properties section of your host control panel, or the Default Document feature under the IIS category in the IIS Manager remote application.

I just had this problem five minutes ago and I realized I forgot to put them in the right order, and had omitted index.php completely.

If that doesn't work, try configuring your site to allow Directory Viewing.